# How can I submit a form when the user presses the `Insert` key?

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can I prompt for confirmation before submitting a form after they press the Insert key, and submit the form without confirmation when the user pushes the Enter/Return key ?

### Summary of actions intended

- **INSERT** : Prompt for confirmation. Submit form if confirmed.
- **ENTER** : Submit form.

### I have the following html form :

```
<form action="hhhhhhh.php" method="post" >
   <input type="text" name="DatInvNew"/>
   <input type="text" name="SumInvNew"/>
   <input type="text" name="KolInvNew"/>
   <input type="submit" value="next"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Please take a look at the solution.  It will submit the form when the user pushes the `ENTER` key, and will prompt form confirmation when the user presses the `INSERT` key.

Comment: This is a horrible idea. Are you trying to mimic some old terminal interface?

Comment: @MaxArt - no judgement here.  The problem has a relatively simple solution. Best we can do for broken logic is to offer clean code at least :).   I have no idea the intent behind it, and see no real security issues.  Perhaps it is a database form of sorts. :S

Comment: I want to score a lot of data quickly. Each time you insert key pressed to record data MSQL table and gives me a new blank form.

Comment: @RadostinKarakerezov - please make up your mind what you wish it to do, then clarify your question.  There are solutions below for two of the 3 different cases you have provided thus far.

Answer (score 0):

The following example does these things (as per the original question) :

- **INSERT** : Prompt for confirmation. Submit form if confirmed.
- **ENTER** : Submit form.

---

```
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if(e.keyCode == 45) {
        if(confirm("Would you like to submit this form?")) {
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
    } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
};
```

And change your html slightly :

```
<form action="hhhhhhh.php" method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="DatInvNew"/>
    <input type="text" name="SumInvNew"/>
    <input type="text" name="KolInvNew"/>
    <input type="submit" value="next"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Try a plain html file, with nothing but the above in it.   Also, instead of 'not working' post screenshots, debug information -- make some attempts yourself.  I have tested this code hosted and it is working as intended.  Make sure javascript is enabled.  Wrap the javascript in  `<script>` `</script>`  and put the script after the form.

Comment: 1. Excuse me for bad English.
2. In your code in both cases makes submit. I want the first input by pressing ENTER to go ana second input. Then the third input and brings me back to the first, if not pressed insert

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer..

Try it once, Just copy and past it..

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inputform').on('keydown', 'input', function (event) {
          switch(event.which) {
            case 13: // enter
        event.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(event.target);
        var index = parseFloat($this.attr('data-index'));
        $('[data-index="' + (index + 1).toString() + '"]').focus();
                break;

            case 45: // insert
        $('#click-to-submit').trigger('click');
        break;
          }
    });
});

</script>
<form id='inputform' action="hhhhhhh.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="DatInvNew" data-index="1" />
    <input type="text" name="SumInvNew" data-index="2" />
    <input type="text" name="KolInvNew" data-index="3" />
    <input type="submit" value="next" class="click-to-submit" id="click-to-submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I condensed the two `keydown` hooks into one, swapped `if` with `switch` and converted to runnable code.  Note that `Insert` doesn't seem to work on any inline demo (here or jsfiddle) likely due to it already being captured/overidden by something else.

Comment: @KraangPrime Pelase check it now, I updated my answer

Comment: @KraangPrime You just need to load "jquery.min.js" first

Comment: Mr. HK - Thank you so much. 
If I have 5 input - data-index= to 5 ?

Comment: @KraangPrime YEs, If you have 5 input - data-index= to 5

Comment: @KraangPrime This is helpful to you or not?

Comment: @Mr.HK I would have left it as runnable code. Aside from that, the code is the same as I edited it except your put into a single non-runnable code-block.  Also, I am not the one who needs this solution

Comment: @RadostinKarakerezov Would you please check this solution ?